# Restoring large hash (> 1GB) from rdb file in Redis

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

My Redis database currently has a large hash table - approx. 130m key/value pairs where each key and value is an integer (obviously stored as string). The hash works fine in the database and consumes < 10GB of memory of 64GB total system memory, per `Redis.info():

```
'used_memory_human': '9.05G'
```

It's computationally expensive to create this hash, taking ~5.5 hours to complete across 16 cores. For this reason I want to be able to dump the hash table to disk and restore it when I stand up the application. I was able to do dump the hash table to disk successfully using:

```
rdb = redis.Redis()

def dump_lookup_table():
    with open('redis_dumps/full_hash.rdb', 'wb') as full_hash_file:
        full_hash_file.write(rdb.dump("my_redis_hash"))
```

This results in a 2.4GB file saved to the relevant folder. The problem is when I try to restore the hash from the file:

```
def restore_lookup_table():
    with open('redis_dumps/full_hash.rdb', 'rb') as full_hash_file:
        rdb.restore("my_redis_hash", 0, full_hash_file.read())

ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.
```

I have tested with a sub-section of the hash (about 25m records), which is a file of ~900MB on disk. This restores successfully, so the issue seems to be a limitation of Redis to accept this very large file for restoration.

In reviewing the docs, it seems that I'm hitting the Query Buffer Hard Limit described [here](https://redis.io/topics/clients), which limits the maximum client buffer to 1GB. Unless I'm misreading the docs and/or the redis.conf file, this doesn't seem to be configurable so I can't increase it to allow the restore of the 2.4GB rdb dump.

One potential workaround that I've found is to create an intermediate temporary has to which I copy a subset of keys, then dump that hash to rdb and delete it. I can then restore the temporary hashes individually and copy the keys into my single desired hash. This works but it's very, very slow in comparison with a simple dump / restore of the single hash.

Is there a generally accepted way to dump / restore relatively large hashes like this? Or is there any way to override or work around the 1GB hard limit on the client buffer?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to backup and restore. Have you tried Redis' recommended method to do it? The [docs](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) say you can simply copy the RDB files while Redis is running. Restoring is, quoting the docs, "basically the same story as backup".

Comment: I'm not trying to backup / restore - I only want to restore this hash, not the whole database.